# Bosch 400Wh battery first led only is flashing and refuses to charge

Tags: electric-bike, battery, charging

On a long trip with a lot of wind my 400Wh battery went empty.When i tried to charge it at home it refuses to charge. The first of the five leds is flashing. Strange because in the manual is written 1,3,5 leds or 2,4 there is nothing about only the fisrt one. Any suggestions?

Comment: Unplug it all, wait overnight, and try again.  If that doesn't change it, take the setup to Batteries Plus.

Comment: I am doing it right now. I have it unplugged watching the first led flashing. Let's see if  it will ever stops flashing. Thank you. I wiil post what happened tomorrow.

Comment: Answer to [this question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/52465/24228) indicate there is a reset function, have you tried that?

Comment: Have you read the update to the other question? The dealer had to do the reset in that case for the battery to come out of its unusable state. You might have to do the same.

Comment: I did. Trying to solve it without the dealer if possible

Comment: Involve the support department of the supplier - they'll tell you if its fixable or if the battery has simply died through age.   Remember batteries are consumables and you should budget for a new one every ~3 years.

Answer (score 1):

When you discharge a lithium-ion battery all the way you can run into serious problems. If the battery is relatively new it may be under warranty and an exchange would be your best bet.

The battery contains electronic circuitry designed to prevent a total discharge. If that circuitry fails the battery is ruined. If the internal voltage of the battery falls below a critical level this circuitry will NOT allow the battery to charge. Your charger's refusal to charge the battery indicates a problem with this circuitry.

If your other options don't work, and you can't exchange the battery for a new one, you can try putting the battery in your fridge (not the freezer) for an hour or so and see if that will help jump start it. Cool for an hour and try charging.

In my experience, once this happens to a battery it's well on it's way to being dead forever, even if you can recharge it once or twice.

Comment: As i mentionrd in the beginning the first of the five leds was flashing. After a few hours the blinking went more rapid until it stopped. Battery still refuges to charge.

Comment: I can't exchange the battery for a new one. I am willing to do the freeze trick, but i dont know how to jump start it after.

Comment: The first led blinking forever indicates the charger is attempting to work, but the battery is not charging.

Comment: DO NOT freeze the battery. Put in the the refidgerator, not the freezer.