# Bosch 500w battery stopped charging

Tags: battery

Charger works as I have a second battery and it charges.  The 500 watt battery displays a partial charge but does not charge and does not power bike.  I have done multiple resets without success.  It is less than one year old.

Comment: Bosch batteries have a two year warranty, take it back to the shop.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's unclear what you're asking

Comment: Many batteries have a built-in charging controller, and this battery may have a defective one.  But also it's often the case that the external charger contains logic to defect problems in the battery, such as a dead cell.

Comment: You could consider trying the Electronics SE site. People here are knowledgeable about acoustic (as opposed to electric) bikes. You may struggle to find someone who can write a good answer about the battery. Of course, the answer could just be that, as @Affe implied, the battery is dead and you should seek recourse if you have it. If you want to learn how to disassemble it to check for and replace a dead cell(s), then definitely the Electronics SE.

Comment: On the plus side, you know your charger, second battery, and bike are all okay.  Just warranty or replace the dead battery.  This is the hidden cost of electric bikes.

Comment: Also, see the Related questions:   specificially   https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52465/bosch-battery-stopped-charging